# Trace calculation from the basis to |+> and |-> states

Tags: quantum-algorithms, linear-algebra

I was reading the paper; https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00055
and going through some of the formulas below and I am a bit stuck between (1) and (2).

How the equation (1) turns into (2) is not clear to me.. Any point or help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the output state (last line of equation 1) be $\sigma$. You're going to measure using projectors (corresponding to a standard basis measurement on the first qubit)
$$
P_+=|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I, \qquad P_-=|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes I
$$
and you want to know the probability of getting the two outcomes $y=\pm$ for a fixed value of $\theta$, so you could write this as
$$
p(y|\theta)=\text{Tr}(P_y\sigma).
$$

Comment: Thank you,  Are you assuming $ + $ is  $|0\rangle $ and $ - $ is  $|1\rangle $ and not the superposition of 0 and 1 states?

Comment: I'm not assuming. They say "if we interpret the 0/1 outcomes of the measurement as +/- respectively"

Comment: @ Daftwullie,   Sorry I missed that part ! :)